# Custom tooltip for legenditem in chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, tooltip, mouseover

To create a legend callback function for a chart, where I want to display a tooltip for the entire row when the user hovers over a legend item or click on a legend item.
The issue I am facing is tooltip is applying only for the last appended child not for the entire row. Need to make the entire row display the tooltip.

Below is my code,

```
`legendCallback: function (chart) {

    var legendTable = document.createElement('table');
    legendTable.classList.add('legend-table');

    chart.data.labels.forEach(function (label, index) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');

        var colorBoxCell = document.createElement('td');
        var colorBox = document.createElement('span');
        colorBox.style.backgroundColor = colorList[index];
        colorBox.classList.add('color-box');
        colorBoxCell.appendChild(colorBox);

        var labelCell = document.createElement('td');
        var labelSpan = document.createElement('span');
        labelSpan.textContent = labels[index].length > 15 ? labels[index].substring(0, 15) + '...' : labels[index];
        labelCell.appendChild(labelSpan);

        var costCell = document.createElement('td');
        var costSpan = document.createElement('span');
        costSpan.textContent = '(' + costs[index] + ')';
        costSpan.style.color = '#2B0A3D';
        costSpan.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        costCell.appendChild(costSpan);

        row.appendChild(colorBoxCell);
        row.appendChild(labelCell);
        row.appendChild(costCell);

        // Set the title attribute for the entire row
        row.title = labels[index] +
            '\ Cost: ' + costs[index];

        // Add onmouseover and onclick events
        row.addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
            console.log('Clicked on legend item:', labels[index]);
            row.title =  labels[index] +
                '\ Cost: ' + costs[index];
        });

        row.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            console.log('Clicked on legend item:', labels[index]);
            row.title = labels[index] +
                '\n Cost: ' + costs[index];
        });

        legendTable.appendChild(row);
    });

    return legendTable.outerHTML;
}`
```

I attempted to streamline and optimize the provided JavaScript code for a chart's legend callback, specifically focusing on creating legend items with tooltips. The primary goals were to simplify the structure, remove redundant code, and ensure tooltips for the entire row.